# How to pass input data from one class to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass the data from one class to another and displayed it in main class i.e user write something in input field(Component A) and at the same time data or input value is display in another component(Component B) and both work is displayed by Component C. But I can't figure out what's wrong with my code. 
Below is my dummy code but the actual code is the same as below.

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super()
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input name="firstName" placeholder="Enter name" />
        )
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1> "Display data here from input of class A " </h1>
        )
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <A />
                <B />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<C />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to any component and that was access through the props of that component 
check full example at https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-yalow-15170?file=/src/index.js

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.name);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <input name="firstName" placeholder="Enter name" />
        )
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(props.framwork);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1> "Display data here from input of class A " </h1>
        )
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <A name="stackoverflow"/>
                <B framwork="react"/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<C />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't, maybe it's syntax error. Can u show me the correct code?

Comment: @RushikeshJade answer updated and added a running example

Comment: No, that's not the answer of my question. Actually user writes something in input field(Component A) and at the same time data or input value is display in another component(Component B) like `event.target.value` and both works is displayed by Component C. Your answer is correct but that's not I want.

Comment: ohh, Right, so you need to follow Data down/ action up strategy, I will update the code

Comment: now check for updated answer https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-yalow-15170?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use callback so that you can send the data from your child component to your parent component again.

```
class A extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super()
    }

    handleChange = () => {
        this.props.getCallBackFromA('triggered A')
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input name="firstName" placeholder="Enter name" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        )
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    componentDidMount= () =>{
        this.props.getCallBackFromB('triggered B')
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <h1> "Display data here from input of class A " </h1>
        )
    }
}

class C extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }
    getCallBackFromA = (value) => {
        console.log('this is value from component A', value)
    }

    getCallBackFromB = (value) => {
        console.log('this is value from component B', value)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <A getCallBackFromA={this.getCallBackFromA}/>
                <B getCallBackFromB={this.getCallBackFromB}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<C />, document.getElementById("root"))
```